# Correct way to mock.patch smtplib.SMTP

Tags: python, mocking, smtplib

Trying to mock.patch a call to `smtplib.SMTP.sendmail` in a unittest. The `sendmail` method appears to be successfully mocked and we can query it as `MagicMock`, but the `called` and `called_args` attributes of the sendmail mock are not correctly updated. It seems likely I'm not applying the patch correctly.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying:

```
import unittest.mock
with unittest.mock.patch('smtplib.SMTP', autospec=True) as mock:
    import smtplib
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    smtp.sendmail('me', 'me', 'hello world\n')
    mock.assert_called()           # <--- this succeeds
    mock.sendmail.assert_called()  # <--- this fails
```

This example generates:

```
AssertionError: Expected 'sendmail' to have been called.
```

If I alter the patch to `smtp.SMTP.sendmail`; eg:

```
with unittest.mock.patch('smtplib.SMTP.sendmail.', autospec=True) as mock:
    ...
```

I can successfully access the `called_args` and `called` attributes of the mock in this case, but because the `smtplib.SMTP` initialization was allowed to take place, an actual smtp-session is established with a host. This is unittesting, and I'd prefer no actual networking take place.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same issue today and forgot that I'm using a context, so just change

```
mock.sendmail.assert_called()
```

to

```
mock.return_value.__enter__.return_value.sendmail.assert_called()
```

That looks messy but here's my example:

```
msg = EmailMessage()
msg['From'] = 'no@no.com'
msg['To'] = 'no@no.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'subject'
msg.set_content('content');

with patch('smtplib.SMTP', autospec=True) as mock_smtp:
    misc.send_email(msg)

    mock_smtp.assert_called()

    context = mock_smtp.return_value.__enter__.return_value
    context.ehlo.assert_called()
    context.starttls.assert_called()
    context.login.assert_called()
    context.send_message.assert_called_with(msg)
```

Comment: Thanks. I marked yours as the answer. I shared my technique as well.

Answer (score 2):

I marked dustymugs's post as the answer, but I discovered another technique to unittest the call that depends on the mocks [method_calls](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.method_calls).

```
import unittest.mock
with unittest.mock.patch('smtplib.SMTP', autospec=True) as mock:
    import smtplib
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    smtp.sendmail('me', 'you', 'hello world\n')

    # Validate sendmail() was called
    name, args, kwargs = smtpmock.method_calls.pop(0)
    self.assertEqual(name, '().sendmail')
    self.assertEqual({}, kwargs)

    # Validate the sendmail() parameters
    from_, to_, body_ = args
    self.assertEqual('me', from_)
    self.assertEqual(['you'], to_)
    self.assertIn('hello world', body_)
```